# CBMC as standalone?

Tags: c, visual-studio, cbmc

is it possible to run CBMC as stand alone witout Visual Express ? Do I need to recompile it or is 
there another trick maybe ?

I only need to use CBMC to translate a function to CNF regularly, so I want to call it with 
the function name, write the cnf file to disk and start again. I do not want to use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely possible to run [The CBMC model checker](http://www.cprover.org/cbmc/) as a standalone program. 
I do it weekly on both Linux and Windows 7 :)

I'm assuming you're on Windows because of Visual Studio.

Open a command prompt and navigate to the folder where `cbmc.exe` is, and call it like so: `cbmc --help` ...to see the options you have.

The [user manual](http://www.cprover.org/cbmc/doc/manual.pdf) has a section on how to do it, in `3.2 Command line interface`.
You may have to call the batch-script that sets up Visual Studio's environment for the CLI (VSVARS32.bat / vsvarsall.bat etc).
On some Windows machines, that script is placed in `c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\[version]\vc\bin\` if I recall correctly.

See this MSDN page for more info on that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats the answer I have looked for.

Comment: @AdrianMonk No problem :) Have a look at the manual if you get stuck, or edit your question further if you have problems. If everything works for you, feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer.

Comment: Tusen Takk. I want to make cnf files, but need to partition then afterwards for better calculating. Did you work on this too ? Maybe Metis ? Ihave a problem to get a cnf file into Metis.

Comment: @AdrianMonk Selv tak :) No I haven't tried exporting theorems/predicates from the SMT backend, but I think it should be possible. I'm not sure about how to get them in CNF form though, but if the output is in the SMT-lib format, maybe there are other tools out there that can. I've seen your other question about this, but I can't help you much though.. May I ask what the application is ?